# How can I implement crash report for android by use of TestFlight?

Tags: android, testflight

I want to know whether TESTFLIGHT sdk automatically detects crashes or am I in need to insert any snippet in my code to know the crash reports?

Comment: do u knew how to launch android feedback widget of testflight??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the Parse documentation and support page and all signs point to yes, the crash reporting is enabled automatically. Looks like there is way you can optimize this to get more statistics by using their Checkpoint API, but the default crash detection should be enabled by the normal integration steps.

**EDIT**

I decided to dig a bit deeper and there is something else that you need to make sure are doing properly for the reports to show.

It looks like you need to sign your application correctly with the debug key if you are still in development.

Check out this post from test flight, at the bottom it states:

"*If you do not see any SDK events in the SDK Debugger or the build's sessions page, please make sure that you correctly signed your app with a debug certificate.*"

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1279775

And here is a link that shows you how to properly sign your application with test flight so the reports do show.

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1277927

Comment: could you please show me the steps with an example I didnot get any crash reports for my application which is uploaded on TESTFLIGHT?

Comment: Hmm I would make sure you have the latest version of the Android SDK and not an older one. The newest version is 1.2, I think in one of the previous versions there was a requirement to add @ReportsCrashes but is not anymore. Other than that, just make sure you followed this guide to setup testflight with the newest SDK. If everything looks correct and still no reports let me know and Ill look deeper into it. https://testflightapp.com/sdk/android/doc/1.2/

Comment: do u knew how to launch android feedback widget of testflight??